# No compatible compatibility setting available for Transfer class in SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I am writing an SMO application, which copies the schema of one database into another.

For this purpose i use `Transfer` class available in `SmoExtended.dll` library.

The sample code is:

```
Database sourceDatabase = sqlServer.Databases[ASourceName];
Transfer t = new Transfer(sourceDatabase);
t.CopyAllObjects = true;
t.CopyData = false;
t.Options.DriAll = true;
t.Options.Triggers = true;
t.DestinationDatabase = ADestinationName;
t.DestinationServer = sqlServer.Name;
t.DestinationLogin = sqlServer.ConnectionContext.Login;
t.DestinationPassword = sqlServer.ConnectionContext.Password;
Database destinationDatabase = new Database(sqlServer, ADestinationName);
destinationDatabase.CompatibilityLevel = CompatibilityLevel.Version100;
destinationDatabase.Create();
t.TransferData();
destinationDatabase.AutoClose = false;
destinationDatabase.Alter();
```

I get an error `Version100 database compatibility level is not supported.`

I am using SMO libraries from the version 100 assembly folder.
The database i am copying and the destination database are both on the same server instance.
The server is `SQL Server 2012`.

I have tried all the available compatibility levels (80,90,100,110), none work. I get the error every time.

HOWEVER, if i use version 110 SMO libraries, everything works as expected, the database is created and schema is copied.

BUT, there is a reason why i can't use version 110 libs, and it's because our clients are using SQL Server 2008 R2, which is a v100 and machines with 2008R2 do not have SDKs of version 110.

PS: Source database compatibility level is set to 100.

Any idea how can i use v100 libs for both, 2008R2 and 2012 and possibly 2014 (this is the last version supporting v100)?

Comment: If you're writing the application, why can't you ship the version 110 DLLs with the executable?

Comment: I guess your solution could work, however need to test it as in general i only need 4 dlls, so not sure how many other dlls are they dependant on. It is either i ship the selected 4 and they work on standalone bases, o i'll have to ship lots of them which inflates the overall space taken by the app.

Comment: Alternatively, installing the SQL 2012 client rules should also install those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1**: (Easy, very little work)

As suggested by `Ben Thul` one could use the libraries of single version (e.g. 110) and ship them with an app, or have clients install SQL server library packs.
I have tested this approach with SQL server 2014 libraries. To achieve the goal, i had to download:
1. Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types (SQLSysClrTypes.msi)
2. Shared Management Objects (SharedManagementObjects.msi)

I have chosen to use x86 libraries, which is 9.3MB in total. These two libraries are enough to get all the SMO libs required.

**SOLUTION 2**: (Harder but still quite easy, much more work)

I have come up with an idea which is a bit harder to implement than the solution 1, but it works.

The idea is to create separate DLL file for each version of SQL Server and dynamicaly load those DLLs.

The steps are as follows:

1. Install or download [Unmanaged exports library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports).
2. Create a new DLL project for a single targeted SQL Server version.
   e.g. `2008.dll`, `2012.dll`...
3. Inside each of the dll i reference corresponding SMO libraries. e.g.
   `2008.dll` i reference DLLs from `..\100\SDK\Assembly`, for SQL
   server 2012 i would do `2012.dll` and reference `..\110\SDK\Assemby`
   and so on.
4. Export the function(s) that i need for calling at my main
   application.

```
[DllExport("Copy", System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static void Copy(string AInstance, string AUser, string APass, string ASourceName, string ADestinationName)
```

5. Define functions for loading and unloading DLLs

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]  
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);  
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]  
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);  
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]  
public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

6. Define function delegate to be used.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private delegate bool CopyDB(string AInstance, string AUser, string APass, string ASourceName, string ADestinationName);
```

7. Load, run and unload depending on a SQL Server version

```
if ( Server.Version.Major == 10 ) {
  IntPtr lib8 = LoadLibrary("2008.dll");
  IntPtr workFunc = GetProcAddress(lib8, "Copy");
  CopyDB dbc = ( CopyDB )Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(workFunc, typeof(CopyDB));
  dbc(SqlInstance, SqlLogin, SqlPassword, ASourceName, ADestinationName);
  FreeLibrary(lib8);
} else if ( Server.Version.Major == 11 ) {
  IntPtr lib12 = LoadLibrary("2012.dll");
  IntPtr workFunc = GetProcAddress(lib12, "Copy");
  CopyDB dbc = ( CopyDB )Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(workFunc, typeof(CopyDB));
  dbc(SqlInstance, SqlLogin, SqlPassword, ASourceName, ADestinationName);
  FreeLibrary(lib12);
} else .....
```

The last step can be generalised even more. We could skip the version check if we were to build dlls with the name like `<version>.dll`, e.g. `10.dll`,`11.dll`,`12.dll`. This way `if .. else ..` is no longer needed and the library that is being loaded will have its name generated at runtime by the value of `Server.Version.Major`

The positive side of this approach is that these targeted DLL files only take ~7KB (for my scenario at least), which is much less than CLR and SMO.msi library packs. It also guarantees that supported SMO libraries will be used. Furthermore, one can distribute a single dll to the clients once a new version of SQL Server is released and the app will happily use it for the newly installed instance.